# Manifest file generated inside meta-inf is missing classpath reference

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to generate jar file for the eclipse project using eclipse export jar feature. I am making absolute reference to a library in my manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true
Main-Class: org.ad.TestMain
Class-Path: D:/demojar/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
```

I also tried with Class-Path: `file:///D:/demojar/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar` and relative path like `lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar`

My project structure is shown here
[image]

I export the jar as shown below making reference to the manifest file

[image]

When I unpack my jar, manifest file generated under meta-inf folder does not contain classpath reference.The code complains about library not existing. How can I resolve this issue?

My main issue here is why classpath generated in the manifest file under meta-inf does not show the classpath referenced?

Comment: Check that text line ends with LF or CRLF -- in the Eclipse editor, with Windows / Preferences General / Editors / TextEditors "show whitespace characters" on, you should see `¶` or `¤¶`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 it resolved my issue, you can post it as an answer so that I can mark it as a right answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `D:` from the classpath and make the path relative to where your main jar is located

i.e)

```
folder/
folder/YourJar.jar
folder/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
```

The manifest should be

```
Main-Class: org.ad.TestMain
Class-Path: lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
```

Comment: I also tried it, but the main issue is why manifest under meta-inf is not showing me the class-path.

Comment: Make sure your library is actually in the location your manifest is specifying

Comment: Drop down referenced libraries, its most likely not at the location you think it is, it has to be relative to your main jar file as well

Comment: In the java project I am making absolute reference to the library(adding external jar)and for jar i am giving absolute path (lib is not inside the jar) so that it can access the jar based on the class-path reference. If i place it in lib folder and built the jar I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Do that then :)

Comment: Goal here is to have a deeper understanding of the jar :)

Comment: Everything is relative to your Jar file, your jar file acts as the root directory for the execution of the program, all paths the jar relies on are either in the same directory or a sub directory of the directory your jar is in

Comment: when i make absolute reference like this file:///D:/demojar/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar the application looks for this path.

Comment: Yes, but don't do that because not all computers will have the same file structure as your computer

Comment: I agree, but the question here is why the manifest file inside meta-inf not showing me the classpath I typed in the manifest.